# Always show 1 view outside of ng-view - angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following controllers, and I want the template of the **CategoryController** to be shown on all pages (ie with all other views). the app displays all categories with this controller, when you click a category it shows all books in that category, then when you click a book it shows the books details. I want the categories to be always shown, can this be done ng-include?

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/books', {
        controller: 'BookshelfController',
        templateUrl: 'views/bookshelf.html'
  })
    .when('/books/:bookId', {
        controller: 'BookController',
        templateUrl: 'views/book.html'
  })
   .when('/categories', {
      controller: 'CategoryController',
      templateUrl: 'views/categories.html'
  })
  .when('/categories/:categoryId', {
    controller: 'BookCategoryController',
    templateUrl: 'views/booksincategory.html'
})
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/books'
  });
});
```

**html**

```
  <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
          <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's better use _angular ui-router multiple views_ see [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Answer (score 0):

As @Hadi says, use angular-ui-router, or why not just place the controller directly over the view when it should be shown on every page, anyway?

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="container"> 
      <div ng-controller="CategoryController"></div>
      <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</div>
```